# Shutil Move brings empty table

Tags: python-2.7, shutil

I am trying to move a CSV file from the Downloads folder into my personal folder. The attached snippet works fine but when I analyze the csv file in my personal folder it is blank, no data is inherent. How can I fix this. Please provide your assistance

```
import shutil 

shutil.move('C:/Users/jake/Downloads/RadGridExport.csv', 'C:\\Users\\jake\\Desktop\\Files\\Python Files\\RadGridExport.csv')
```

Comment: Just checking, did you make sure that there's something in it when it's in your downloads folder?

Comment: Yes the csv file in my downloads folder has 5 kb of data.

Comment: You are using forward slash `/` in the first argument, and backward slashes in the second argument. Not sure how this works on windows.